# Why is the 'r' variable can be referenced in this code?

Tags: python

I am reading someone's code as below, and I have 2 questions:
1) Where is the 'r' from in 'r.message'? It is not defined before it.
2) For this 2 lines:

```
for r in intent_results
if r.intent_target != r.intent_prediction
```

The `if` statement is not indented and it didn't report any error message, Why is that?

```
def collect_nlu_errors(intent_results, errors_filename):
    """Log messages which result in wrong predictions and save them to file"""

    errors = [
        {
            "text": r.message,
            "intent": r.intent_target,
            "intent_prediction": {
                "name": r.intent_prediction,
                "confidence": r.confidence,
            },
        }
        for r in intent_results
        if r.intent_target != r.intent_prediction
    ]

    if errors:
        utils.write_json_to_file(errors_filename, errors)
        logger.info("Model prediction errors saved to {}.".format(errors_filename))
        logger.debug(
            "\n\nThese intent examples could not be classified "
            "correctly: \n{}".format(errors)
        )
    else:
        logger.info("Your model made no errors")
```

Comment: Those aren't individual `for` and `if` statements, the entire expression for `errors` is a single *list comprehension* that's spread out over rather more lines than usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question:

This is an example of a Python inline list comprehension. To explain what this does here's a simpler example:

```
first_names = [person['first_name'] for person in people]
```

For a list of people in the form of

```
people = [{'first_name': "John", 'last_name': "Doe"}, {'first_name': "Jane", 'last_name': "Doe"}]
```

the above will return a list

```
['Jane', 'John']
```

This was introduced in [PEP202](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/). It's a great way of making readable yet succinct code (assuming it's not abused).

Second question:

It looks to be indented properly. As long as `errors` is defined beforehand you won't get a NameError.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I stand corrected. Updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it [this way](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[a for r in intent_results if condition]
```

where `a` represents:

```
{
    "text": r.message,
    "intent": r.intent_target,
    "intent_prediction": {
        "name": r.intent_prediction,
        "confidence": r.confidence,
    },
}
```

and `condition` is

```
r.intent_target != r.intent_prediction
```

Answer (score 1):

The r in `for r in intent_results` is just an arbitrary letter that the programmer chose.There is another object called r e.g `r.message` which is probably a global variable available to the function that you have not included.

Python is not like other languages where you have to explicitly define a variable before using it - you see such examples in e.g. list comprehensions.

As for no error being thrown, its because the `if` statement is contained in a list.

```
errors = [ << - beginning of list
    {
        "text": r.message,
        "intent": r.intent_target,
        "intent_prediction": {
            "name": r.intent_prediction,
            "confidence": r.confidence,
        },
    }
    for r in intent_results
    if r.intent_target != r.intent_prediction
] << - end of list
```

This is wrong. I suspect the intended code was:

```
def collect_nlu_errors(intent_results, errors_filename):
    """Log messages which result in wrong predictions and save them to file"""

    errors = [
        {
            "text": r.message,
            "intent": r.intent_target,
            "intent_prediction": {
                "name": r.intent_prediction,
                "confidence": r.confidence,
            },
        }
    ]
    for r in intent_results:
        if r.intent_target != r.intent_prediction:

            if errors:
                utils.write_json_to_file(errors_filename, errors)
                logger.info("Model prediction errors saved to {}.".format(errors_filename))
                logger.debug(
                    "\n\nThese intent examples could not be classified "
                    "correctly: \n{}".format(errors)
                )
            else:
                logger.info("Your model made no errors")
```

In my editor i get errors on the lines with `utils` , `r` and `logger`. As mentioned earlier, these may be global variables as they are not passed into the function.

Hope that helps.